start multiple jobs on one node in multiple slurm files
I want to use slurm to tell a server it can put multiple jobs on each node (either until max or until a given threshold). I want to do this using one slurm file (and one sbatch command) per job. Every node on the server I am using has multiple cores. I have many jobs that each need only one core.
I have found multiple answers where multiple jobs are started from the same slurm file, but I'd prefer not to do that.
I have tried using --nodes=1 and --ntasks=1 together, but still the jobs were simply queued and not put on the same node.
My slurm file is
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=<partition-name>
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --output=<outputfile>
#SBATCH --error=<errorfile>

# run command
<command to run>


By default, Slurm does not oversubscribe cores on a node unless explicitly configured. Your jobs are likely being queued because SLURM is waiting for a complete node to become available, even if only one core is needed.
You need to ensure that SLURM is configured to allow multiple jobs to share nodes. This is generally done by setting the SelectType and SelectTypeParameters in the SLURM configuration file (slurm.conf).
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core

SelectType=select/cons_res: This sets the resource selection plugin to "Consumable Resources", which allows more fine-grained control over resources like CPU cores and memory.
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core: This allows Slurm to schedule jobs based on the number of CPU cores required.
You can check your current settings by running the following command:
scontrol show config | grep -E "SelectType|SelectTypeParameters"


Thanks! The setting here is "SelectType = select/linear" and no setting for "SelectTypeParameters". I'll ask my admin.

However, would this then automatically allow to start jobs on the same node from multiple slurm files?
